# Find nearest RGB value using color palette array in C

Tags: c, colors, rgb, bmp

I have some part of code done, but in some comparisons, nearest values are incorrectly.
Example:

**Correct:**

```
Rgb value | Value from array
0xFFFFFD  = 0xFFFFFF
```

**Incorrect:**
*Fixed code*

```
Rgb value | Value from array
0xF4F939  = 0xFF0000 (should be 0xFFFF00)
```

**Console Output: (Correct)**

```
C:\Users\honguito\Desktop\Bat\Game_Batch_Files\24_to_8_bitmap>24_to_8_bit_palett
e
The closest color of 0xFFFFFD is: '0xFFFFFF'

C:\Users\honguito\Desktop\Bat\Game_Batch_Files\24_to_8_bitmap>
```

**Console Output: (Incorrect)**

```
C:\Users\honguito\Desktop\Bat\Game_Batch_Files\24_to_8_bitmap>24_to_8_bit_palett
e
The closest color of 0xF4F939 is: '0xFF0000'

C:\Users\honguito\Desktop\Bat\Game_Batch_Files\24_to_8_bitmap>
```

---

Those RGB color code are listed in an array:

```
int data[] = {
    0x000000, 0x800000, 0x008000, 0x808000, 0x000080, 0x800080, 0x008080,
    0xC0C0C0, 0xC0DCC0, 0xA6CAF0, 0x402000, 0x602000, 0x802000, 0xA02000,
    0xC02000, 0xE02000, 0x004000, 0x204000, 0x404000, 0x604000, 0x804000,
    0xA04000, 0xC04000, 0xE04000, 0x006000, 0x206000, 0x406000, 0x606000,
    0x806000, 0xA06000, 0xC06000, 0xE06000, 0x008000, 0x208000, 0x408000,
    0x608000, 0x808000, 0xA08000, 0xC08000, 0xE08000, 0x00A000, 0x20A000,
    0x40A000, 0x60A000, 0x80A000, 0xA0A000, 0xC0A000, 0xE0A000, 0x00C000,
    0x20C000, 0x40C000, 0x60C000, 0x80C000, 0xA0C000, 0xC0C000, 0xE0C000,
    0x00E000, 0x20E000, 0x40E000, 0x60E000, 0x80E000, 0xA0E000, 0xC0E000,
    0xE0E000, 0x000040, 0x200040, 0x400040, 0x600040, 0x800040, 0xA00040,
    0xC00040, 0xE00040, 0x002040, 0x202040, 0x402040, 0x602040, 0x802040,
    0xA02040, 0xC02040, 0xE02040, 0x004040, 0x204040, 0x404040, 0x604040,
    0x804040, 0xA04040, 0xC04040, 0xE04040, 0x006040, 0x206040, 0x406040,
    0x606040, 0x806040, 0xA06040, 0xC06040, 0xE06040, 0x008040, 0x208040,
    0x408040, 0x608040, 0x808040, 0xA08040, 0xC08040, 0xE08040, 0x00A040,
    0x20A040, 0x40A040, 0x60A040, 0x80A040, 0xA0A040, 0xC0A040, 0xE0A040,
    0x00C040, 0x20C040, 0x40C040, 0x60C040, 0x80C040, 0xA0C040, 0xC0C040,
    0xE0C040, 0x00E040, 0x20E040, 0x40E040, 0x60E040, 0x80E040, 0xA0E040,
    0xC0E040, 0xE0E040, 0x000080, 0x200080, 0x400080, 0x600080, 0x800080,
    0xA00080, 0xC00080, 0xE00080, 0x002080, 0x202080, 0x402080, 0x602080,
    0x802080, 0xA02080, 0xC02080, 0xE02080, 0x004080, 0x204080, 0x404080,
    0x604080, 0x804080, 0xA04080, 0xC04080, 0xE04080, 0x006080, 0x206080,
    0x406080, 0x606080, 0x806080, 0xA06080, 0xC06080, 0xE06080, 0x008080,
    0x208080, 0x408080, 0x608080, 0x808080, 0xA08080, 0xC08080, 0xE08080,
    0x00A080, 0x20A080, 0x40A080, 0x60A080, 0x80A080, 0xA0A080, 0xC0A080,
    0xE0A080, 0x00C080, 0x20C080, 0x40C080, 0x60C080, 0x80C080, 0xA0C080,
    0xC0C080, 0xE0C080, 0x00E080, 0x20E080, 0x40E080, 0x60E080, 0x80E080,
    0xA0E080, 0xC0E080, 0xE0E080, 0x0000C0, 0x2000C0, 0x4000C0, 0x6000C0,
    0x8000C0, 0xA000C0, 0xC000C0, 0xE000C0, 0x0020C0, 0x2020C0, 0x4020C0,
    0x6020C0, 0x8020C0, 0xA020C0, 0xC020C0, 0xE020C0, 0x0040C0, 0x2040C0,
    0x4040C0, 0x6040C0, 0x8040C0, 0xA040C0, 0xC040C0, 0xE040C0, 0x0060C0,
    0x2060C0, 0x4060C0, 0x6060C0, 0x8060C0, 0xA060C0, 0xC060C0, 0xE060C0,
    0x0080C0, 0x2080C0, 0x4080C0, 0x6080C0, 0x8080C0, 0xA080C0, 0xC080C0,
    0xE080C0, 0x00A0C0, 0x20A0C0, 0x40A0C0, 0x60A0C0, 0x80A0C0, 0xA0A0C0,
    0xC0A0C0, 0xE0A0C0, 0x00C0C0, 0x20C0C0, 0x40C0C0, 0x60C0C0, 0x80C0C0,
    0xA0C0C0, 0xFFFBF0, 0xA0A0A4, 0x808080, 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0xFFFF00,
    0x0000FF, 0xFF00FF, 0x00FFFF, 0xFFFFFF
};
```

---

Then to get the nearest number I do:

```
nearest = findKey(data, pcolor);
```

And this is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    //int pcolor = 0xF4F939;
    int pcolor = 0xFFFFFD;
    //int pcolor = 0x700000;
    //int pcolor = 0x21A0C0;
    int cmp[256];
    int cmp2[256];
    int data[] = {
        0x000000, 0x800000, 0x008000, 0x808000, 0x000080, 0x800080, 0x008080,
        0xC0C0C0, 0xC0DCC0, 0xA6CAF0, 0x402000, 0x602000, 0x802000, 0xA02000,
        0xC02000, 0xE02000, 0x004000, 0x204000, 0x404000, 0x604000, 0x804000,
        0xA04000, 0xC04000, 0xE04000, 0x006000, 0x206000, 0x406000, 0x606000,
        0x806000, 0xA06000, 0xC06000, 0xE06000, 0x008000, 0x208000, 0x408000,
        0x608000, 0x808000, 0xA08000, 0xC08000, 0xE08000, 0x00A000, 0x20A000,
        0x40A000, 0x60A000, 0x80A000, 0xA0A000, 0xC0A000, 0xE0A000, 0x00C000,
        0x20C000, 0x40C000, 0x60C000, 0x80C000, 0xA0C000, 0xC0C000, 0xE0C000,
        0x00E000, 0x20E000, 0x40E000, 0x60E000, 0x80E000, 0xA0E000, 0xC0E000,
        0xE0E000, 0x000040, 0x200040, 0x400040, 0x600040, 0x800040, 0xA00040,
        0xC00040, 0xE00040, 0x002040, 0x202040, 0x402040, 0x602040, 0x802040,
        0xA02040, 0xC02040, 0xE02040, 0x004040, 0x204040, 0x404040, 0x604040,
        0x804040, 0xA04040, 0xC04040, 0xE04040, 0x006040, 0x206040, 0x406040,
        0x606040, 0x806040, 0xA06040, 0xC06040, 0xE06040, 0x008040, 0x208040,
        0x408040, 0x608040, 0x808040, 0xA08040, 0xC08040, 0xE08040, 0x00A040,
        0x20A040, 0x40A040, 0x60A040, 0x80A040, 0xA0A040, 0xC0A040, 0xE0A040,
        0x00C040, 0x20C040, 0x40C040, 0x60C040, 0x80C040, 0xA0C040, 0xC0C040,
        0xE0C040, 0x00E040, 0x20E040, 0x40E040, 0x60E040, 0x80E040, 0xA0E040,
        0xC0E040, 0xE0E040, 0x000080, 0x200080, 0x400080, 0x600080, 0x800080,
        0xA00080, 0xC00080, 0xE00080, 0x002080, 0x202080, 0x402080, 0x602080,
        0x802080, 0xA02080, 0xC02080, 0xE02080, 0x004080, 0x204080, 0x404080,
        0x604080, 0x804080, 0xA04080, 0xC04080, 0xE04080, 0x006080, 0x206080,
        0x406080, 0x606080, 0x806080, 0xA06080, 0xC06080, 0xE06080, 0x008080,
        0x208080, 0x408080, 0x608080, 0x808080, 0xA08080, 0xC08080, 0xE08080,
        0x00A080, 0x20A080, 0x40A080, 0x60A080, 0x80A080, 0xA0A080, 0xC0A080,
        0xE0A080, 0x00C080, 0x20C080, 0x40C080, 0x60C080, 0x80C080, 0xA0C080,
        0xC0C080, 0xE0C080, 0x00E080, 0x20E080, 0x40E080, 0x60E080, 0x80E080,
        0xA0E080, 0xC0E080, 0xE0E080, 0x0000C0, 0x2000C0, 0x4000C0, 0x6000C0,
        0x8000C0, 0xA000C0, 0xC000C0, 0xE000C0, 0x0020C0, 0x2020C0, 0x4020C0,
        0x6020C0, 0x8020C0, 0xA020C0, 0xC020C0, 0xE020C0, 0x0040C0, 0x2040C0,
        0x4040C0, 0x6040C0, 0x8040C0, 0xA040C0, 0xC040C0, 0xE040C0, 0x0060C0,
        0x2060C0, 0x4060C0, 0x6060C0, 0x8060C0, 0xA060C0, 0xC060C0, 0xE060C0,
        0x0080C0, 0x2080C0, 0x4080C0, 0x6080C0, 0x8080C0, 0xA080C0, 0xC080C0,
        0xE080C0, 0x00A0C0, 0x20A0C0, 0x40A0C0, 0x60A0C0, 0x80A0C0, 0xA0A0C0,
        0xC0A0C0, 0xE0A0C0, 0x00C0C0, 0x20C0C0, 0x40C0C0, 0x60C0C0, 0x80C0C0,
        0xA0C0C0, 0xFFFBF0, 0xA0A0A4, 0x808080, 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0xFFFF00,
        0x0000FF, 0xFF00FF, 0x00FFFF, 0xFFFFFF
    };

    int nearIndex,nearest, result;

    nearest = findKey(data, pcolor);    
    printf("The closest color of 0x%X is: '0x%X'\n", pcolor, nearest);
    //system("pause");
}


int findKey(int Array1[], int key){
    int diff = abs( key - Array1[0]);
    int Num1 = 0;
    int Num2 = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
            if (diff > abs( key - Array1[a] )) {
            diff = abs( key - Array1[a]);
            Num1 = Array1[a];
        }
    }
    return Num1;
    }
```

*There are some unused variables and old code.*

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually according to the definition used by your code for "nearness" (absolute difference) the code is correct: the difference between 0xFF0000 and 0x21A0C0 is smaller than between 0xFFF000 and the same.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong, in the second code block, it's 0xF4F939 instead 0x21A0C0. Sorry for that!

Comment: It's still the same situation. Do a subtraction with a calculator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the "optical" closest color you have to estimate the difference between the color components of the two color you're comparing.

In order to do that you have to split the 24 bit value into 8 bit color components r, g, b.

Then you compare the components.

A naive method to do that is just sum the absolute value of the difference of the respective components.

More accurate formulas can be found googling, I guess.

```
// two colors to compare

int c1;
int c2;

// split c1 and c2 into their respective color components

r1 = c1 / 0x010000;
g1 = (c1 % 0x010000) / 0x00100;
b1 = c1 % 0x000100;

r2 = c2 / 0x010000;
g2 = (c2 % 0x010000) / 0x00100;
b2 = c2 % 0x000100;

// color "distance"

diff = abs( r1 - r2 ) + abs( g1 - g2 ) + abs ( b1 - b2 );
```

Comment: Initially, I tried to get RGB composite diff between pcolor and data[] array. But I never tried to split RGB hex code to 3 variables.

P.S: There is an another way more efficient to split RGB hex code using logical shifts.
P.S 2: Thanks for help me!

Comment: sure, there are more efficient ways to split the color; my code was just to give the idea. Also there may be more otpical-accurate formulas to compare colors based on the components' values. But again it was just to give the idea, that is: "first split the color into components".You're welcome

Comment: As [John Hascall](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25715571/2564301) notes in his answer, a distance is best measured Euclidean.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that using the 3-D distance formula would be a more accurate way to compute the 'nearest' color (since you only care about comparing, you can skip the `sqrt()` at the end).

```
dist_r = abs(r1 - r2);
dist_g = abs(g1 - g2);
dist_b = abs(b1 - b2);
dist_3d_sqd = (dist_r * dist_r) + (dist_g * dist_g) + (dist_b * dist_b
```

actually you can skip the `abs()` calls too, but putting them in makes it clearer, perhaps?

Comment: Won't the `abs()` calls make it a tad bit slower? We could perhaps explain the need for the `dist_` variables in a comment rather than including an `abs()` call