# how to get the difference value in the following code

Tags: c#, arrays, list, colors, difference

I have the following code:

```
Double[] colorED = new Double[75];
Double[,] ColorEd = new Double[10, 10];
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < (colorfeature3.Count()) / color_no; i2++)
  {
      int cj = 0;
      for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 10; i3++)
   {
ColorEd[ci,cj]= (Math.Abs(colorfeature3[i2 * color_no + i3].GetHue()- colorarray[i3].GetHue()) + Math.Abs(colorfeature3[i2 * color_no + i3].GetSaturation() - colorarray[i3].GetSaturation()) +Math.Abs (colorfeature3[i2 * color_no + i3].GetBrightness() - colorarray[i3].GetBrightness()));
   } 
  }
```

what I want is to get the difference between each one of the elements of colorarray(that contains 10 elements) and 10 elements of the colorfeature3(the array contains 750 element each 10 element are separate from other because it represent a feature of an image in the dataset) and save the difference values to 10*10 array then get the minimum of each row and save it to list

anyone can help?

Comment: what does *nearest* mean? is this an RGB colorspace?

Comment: Show us your code and where you fail, so we can help

Comment: Please check out [the StackOverflow guidelines for asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define what "nearest color" means. Here's an answer that might be helpful: [Find nearest RGB value using color palette array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25613004/179311).

```
public int Closeness(int c1, int c2)
{
    // Example algorithm
    int r1 = c1 / 0x010000 - c2 / 0x010000;
    int g1 = (c1 % 0x010000) / 0x00100 - (c2 % 0x010000) / 0x00100;
    int b1 = c1 % 0x000100 - c2 % 0x000100;
    return r1 * r1 + g1 * g1 + b1 * b1;
}
```

Second, you'll need to create a sort function that uses this "nearness" algorithm to find the closest color in your master color list.

```
 public int FindClosestIndex(List<int> master, int color)
{
    var idx = -1;
    var idxCloseness = int.MaxValue;
    for (var i = 0; i < master.Count; i++)
    {
        var closeness = Closeness(master[i], color);
        if (closeness < idxCloseness)
        {
            idx = i;
            idxCloseness = closeness;
        }
    }
    return idxCloseness;
}

public int SortColorByMasterList(List<int> masterOrder, int a, int b)
{
    return FindClosestIndex(masterOrder, a).CompareTo(FindClosestIndex(masterOrder, b));
}
```

And you use it something like this:

```
myList.Sort((a,b) => SortColorByMasterList(masterOrder, a, b));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but execuse me what does the value 0x000100 is needed for can you explain please

Comment: I pretty much copied from the other post I linked to, but the idea is to return only the individual colors (red, green, and blue) from a hex color. To get red, you take only the first two digits (0x##0000) so we remove the last 4 digits (color / 0x0010000). Blue requires stripping the red off, so we modulo (color % 0x1000) and then strip off green by dividing by 0x100. And so on. Your colors may or not be integers, you didn't specify much in the question itself.

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to mention that i am using rgb color system and their values are integers thanks for help